# Adding web controls to asp.net table at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I would like to add asp.net literal web controls to a table at runtime at regular timer intervals. The controls will get there static values from an instance of a class that is an array.

I am not an OOP buff but from my understanding I need to declare this class once and then keep referring to the values it is storing since I will need these values to provide text values for the web controls.

Here is the thing I keep getting null reference exception thrown despite initializing not just the class as an array, but each of the items in the array of the class.

Why?

EDIT:

Here are the class declarations and initialization functions:

```
public class Names
{
    String name = ""; public String Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    Byte name_id = 0; public Byte NameID { get { return name_id; } set { name_id = value; } }
    Decimal point = 0; public Decimal Point { get { return point; } set { point = value; } }
    Int64 index = 0; public Int64 Index { get { return index; } set { index = value; } }
    String quote = ""; public String Quote { get { return quote; } set { quote = value; } }
    Boolean initialised = false; public Boolean Initialised { get { return initialised; } set { initialised = value; } }
}


public static Names[] _names;

public static void NamesInitialise(Names[] names)
{
    names = new Names[10];
    //
    names[0] = new Names();
    names[0].Name = "LOSANGELES";
    names[0].NameID = 14;
    names[0].Index = 0;
    names[0].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[0].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[1] = new Names();
    names[1].Name = "STOCKHOLM";
    names[1].NameID = 15;
    names[1].Index = 1;
    names[1].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.001);
    names[1].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[2] = new Names();
    names[2].Name = "BERLIN";
    names[2].NameID = 21;
    names[2].Index = 2;
    names[2].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[2].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[3] = new Names();
    names[3].Name = "BONN";
    names[3].NameID = 23;
    names[3].Index = 3;
    names[3].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[3].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[4] = new Names();
    names[4].Name = "PARIS";
    names[4].NameID = 24;
    names[4].Index = 4;
    names[4].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[4].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[5] = new Names();
    names[5].Name = "TELAVIV";
    names[5].NameID = 25;
    names[5].Index = 5;
    names[5].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.001);
    names[5].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[6] = new Names();
    names[6].Name = "ROME";
    names[6].NameID = 31;
    names[6].Index = 6;
    names[6].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[6].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[7] = new Names();
    names[7].Name = "NEWYORK";
    names[7].NameID = 34;
    names[7].Index = 7;
    names[7].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00001);
    names[7].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[8] = new Names();
    names[8].Name = "LONDON";
    names[8].NameID = 35;
    names[8].Index = 8;
    names[8].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.001);
    names[8].Initialised = true;
    //
    names[9] = new Names();
    names[9].Name = "TOKYO";
    names[9].NameID = 45;
    names[9].Index = 9;
    names[9].Point = Convert.ToDecimal(0.001);
    names[9].Initialised = true;
    //
}



public class Base : Names
{
    Decimal basis = 0; public Decimal Basis { get { return basis; } set { basis = value; } }
}

public static Base[] _base;
```

And this is how I use them on a timer

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table1.Rows.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_yahoo[i].Initialised||!_names[i].Initialised||!_base[i].Initialised)
            {
                NamesInitialise(_yahoo);
                NamesInitialise(_names);
                NamesInitialise(_base);
            }
            else
            {
                Yahoo_Load(_yahoo[i]);
                //
                TableRow _table_row = new TableRow();
                Table1.Rows.Add(_table_row);
                //
                TableCell _cell_1 = new TableCell();
                _cell_1.Text = _names[i].Name;
                _table_row.Cells.Add(_cell_1);
                //
                TableCell _cell_2 = new TableCell();
                _cell_2.Text = Convert.ToString(_base[_names[i].Index].Basis);
                _table_row.Cells.Add(_cell_2);
                //
                TableCell _cell_3 = new TableCell();
                _cell_3.Text = _names[i].Quote;
                _table_row.Cells.Add(_cell_3);
                //
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Commented this out on purpose and null exception errors are thrown. 
            //That should not be the case.
            /*
            NamesInitialise(_yahoo);
            NamesInitialise(_names);
            NamesInitialise(_base);
            */
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your function NamesInitialise is wrong.

```
public static void NamesInitialise(Names[] names)
{
    names = new Names[10];
```

You are internally creating array, which do not replace passed variable.

Change to

```
public static Names[] NamesInitialise()
{
    var names = new Names[10];
    .....
    return names;
}
```

Beside of this, initialize arrays before iterating inside loop.

And more, you are populating all rows with single tick, which is probalby wrong, no progressive adding rows is here.

And more, table do not preserve rows/cells added in previous postback